# JPA fetch lazy never worked

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, fetch

I have some problem using Eclipselink JPA

I have two entities:

Parent

```
public class Journal implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotBlank
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "JOURNALNAME", unique = true, length = 70)
private String journalname;
@NotBlank
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "PATHNAME", unique = true, length = 70)
private String pathname;
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "ISSN", unique = true, length = 70)
private String issn;
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "PRINCIPALNAME", length = 70)
private String principalname;
@Email
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "PRINCIPALEMAIL", length = 70)
private String principalEmail;
@Column(name = "PRINCIPALPHONE", length = 70)
private String principalPhone;
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "PRINCIPALFAX", length = 70)
private String principalFax;
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "TECHNICALSUPPORT", length = 70)
private String technicalSupport;
@Email
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "TECHNICALSUPPORTEMAIL", length = 70)
private String technicalSupportEmail;
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "TECHNICALSUPPORTPHONE", length = 70)
private String technicalSupportPhone;
@Size(max = 200)
@Column(name = "EMAILSIGNATURE", length = 200)
private String emailSignature;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "FOCUSSCOPE", length = 4000)
private String focusScope;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "REVIEWPOLICY", length = 4000)
private String reviewPolicy;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "REVIEWERGUIDELINES", length = 4000)
private String reviewerGuidelines;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "COPYEDITORGUIDELINES", length = 4000)
private String copyeditorGuidelines;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "PROOFREADERGUIDELINES", length = 4000)
private String proofreaderGuidelines;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "LAYOUTEDITORGUIDELINES", length = 4000)
private String layouteditorGuidelines;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "AUTHORGUIDELINES", length = 4000)
private String authorGuidelines;
@Column(name = "TYPICALREVIEWTIME")
private Integer typicalReviewTime;
@Size(max = 4000)
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 4000)
private String description;
@Column(name = "HOSTED")
private boolean hosted;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "journal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Submission> submissionList;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "journal", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<IntUserRoleJournal> intUserRoleJournalList;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "journal")
private List<JournalSubmissionCheck> journalSubmissionCheckList;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "journal", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Announcement> announcementList;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "journal", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Form> formList;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "journal", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Issue> issueList;
```

and child :

```
public class Issue implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 150)
@Column(name = "IDENTIFY", length = 150)
private String identify;
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "TITLE", length = 70)
private String title;
@Column(name = "VOLUME", length = 5)
private String volume;
@Column(name = "NUMBER", length = 5)
private String number;
@Column(name = "YEAR", length = 4)
private String year;
@Column(name = "PUBLISH")
private boolean publish;
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
Date publishDate;
@Size(max = 7000)
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION",columnDefinition = "text")
private String description;
@Size(max = 70)
@Column(name = "COVER", length = 70, unique = true)
private String cover;
@ManyToOne
private Journal journal;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "issue", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Attachment> galleyList;
```

The problem is when I try to create a new issue. Journal, as parent always fetch all issue list I've created before. even I set fetchType.lazy. The only way to stop its eager behaviour is to remove the getter method in parent class.

```
 public String createIssue() {
    FacesMessage msg = null;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (valueVolume == false
            && valueNumber == false
            && valueYear == false
            && valueTitle == false) {
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Please spesify at least one issue identification", null);
    } else {
        try {
            issue.setJournal(journal);
            setIdentify();
            JournalRegistry.getCurrentInstance().createIssue(issue);
            journal.getIssueList().add(issue);
            JournalRegistry.getCurrentInstance().updateJournal(journal);
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Issue created", null);
            reset();
        } catch (EntityAccessorException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HeaIssueCreateB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "Occured error. "
                    + "Please try to refresh page or contact support", null);
        }
    }
    fc.addMessage(null, msg);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need javassist for lazy to work in eclipselink?

Comment: does jpa need javassist to enable oneToMany lazy relationship ?

Comment: No, but it does for change tracking.  By accessing the collection you are triggering the lazy relation, forcing it to be fetched.  Change tracking can allow for adding to some collections without the need to fetch them.

Comment: my lazy fetchType work, by unspesifying shared cache mode.

Comment: does it mean that JPA normally always fetch all data from cache and ignored lazy and javaasist needed to help stop it's behavior?